# Android Kotling Extension for Binding a Generic View

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I have a generic custom view like

```
class MyGenericCustomView<T>(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AnotherView(context, attrs) {
    ...
}
```

In the Activity/Fragment XML I have:

```
<package.name.MyGenericCustomView
   android:id="@+id/custom_id"
   ....
/>
```

If I use the old way, I can get my "typed" custom view using something like:

```
override fun onCreate(...) {
    ...
    val myCustomView = findViewById<MyGenericCustomView<String>>(R.id.custom_id)
    ...
}
```

But if I use the Android Kotlin Extension (synthetic) to have an object named with the same ID, I dont have a way to pass the Generic type, so

```
//custom_id is of type MyGenericCustomView<*>
```

One solution is to create a specific class like

```
class MySpecificCustomView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : MyGenericCustomView<String>(context, attrs) {
    ....
}
```

But I dont want to create this boilerplate class.
Is there any solution to specify a custom type using Kotlin Extensions only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot specify the type parameter in the XML and type parameters are also erased in the byte code, you could simply cast the value to the proper generic type `MyGenericCustomView<String>`.

So something like that should work:

```
val myView = custom_id as MyGenericCustomView<String>
```

For better usage in your Activity/Fragment I would personally use `lazy { }` like this:

```
class MyActivity() : Activity(…) {

    val myView by lazy { custom_id as MyGenericCustomView<String> }

    ...
}
```